# Exclamation mark for HTML attribute

Tags: html

I'm looking at an ancient website and I see `!style="width:380px; height:30px;"` inside an input element. What does the exclamation mark mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not mean anything. It is invalid markup, and no meaning is assigned to it, any more than an attribute specification like `vjkfhjidfhgsi="fbhhjgf"` has a meaning.

It has an effect, though, but only in the sense that the specification is parsed and an entry is created from it into the `attributes` object of the element node, with `!style` as the attribute name. This has no effect in itself, but such an attribute could be used in scripting and in CSS.

If you meant to ask *why* the exclamation mark was used, then your guess in your own answer may well be correct. Though invalid, the method is probably *safer* now than it was in the past. In the old days, syntax error handling was not defined for HTML, and one might argue that HTML parsers could well just skip a character like `!` in this context and process the tag as if it were not there. In HTML5 parsing rules, which largely just make common browser practice the rule, specify the `!` is to be taken as the first character of an attribute name, see 8.2.4.34 [Before attribute name state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#before-attribute-name-state) and the next clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no way to comment out an attribute in HTML, this is probably a hack to make the attribute invalid and thus the styles are not applied. The exclamation mark is probably a convention used by the developer to mark all his/her unneeded attributes.